# C++ design: container of instances and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

I'm wondering something.

I have class `Polygon`, which composes a vector of `Line` (another class here)

```
class Polygon
{
  std::vector<Line> lines;

public:
  const_iterator begin() const;

  const_iterator end() const;

}
```

On the other hand, I have a function, that calculates a vector of pointers to lines, and based on those lines, should return a pointer to a `Polygon`.

```
 Polygon* foo(Polygon& p){

  std::vector<Line> lines = bar (p.begin(),p.end());

  return new Polygon(lines);

 }
```

Here's the question:

I can always add a Polygon (vector

Is there a better way than dereferencing each element of the vector and assigning it to the existing vector container?

```
//for line in vector<Line*> v
//vcopy is an instance of vector<Line>
vcopy.push_back(*(v.at(i))
```

I think not, but I don't really like that approach.

Hopefully, I will be able to convince the author of the class to change it, but I can't base my coding right now to that fact (and I'm scared of a performance hit).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612324/c-design-question-container-of-instances-and-pointers

Comment: @Nathan: this is the original.

Comment: @Potatocorn: no, there's even an earlier one

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612319/c-design-question-container-of-instances-and-pointers

Comment: My bad, I pressed enter a couple of times really fast

Comment: @Eli: Bah, three! And now I've posted an answer.

Comment: @Alloftheabove Removed the  other questions.

Comment: @Nathan and @Ben: Both the links are broken. Before hitting "close" on any question, you should at least check whether the links you are posting are valid.

Comment: @Rahul: Those questions got closed, but the links probably still worked when Nathan and Ben posted their comments.

Comment: Well, in that case, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `transform()` the container:

```
struct deref { // NO! I don't want to derive, LEAVE ME ALONE!
    template<typename P>
    const P& operator()(const P* const p) const { return *p; }
};

// ...
    vector<Line*> orig; // assume full ...
    vector<Line> cp(orig.size());
    transform(orig.begin(), orig.end(), cp.begin(), deref());
```

Comment: This looks much better.
Thanks, i was looking for something like this.

Comment: If it's expensive to create a default `Line` object then don't pass `orig.size()` to the ctor of `cp`. Rather, construct `cp` empty and then call `cp.reserve(orig.size())`. This will result in an extra line of code but will avoid initializing each `Line` object (through the default ctor of `Line`, supposedly an expensive operation) in `cp`.

Comment: @Tom no, `deref` isn't a template. It's a regular struct that has a template member function. The `transform()` algorithm doesn't need to instantiate the template `deref::operator()()` (i.e. It Just Works(tm)) because the compiler can deduce the template arguments through the function's arguments.

Comment: @Tom the reason I didn't derive from `std::unary_function` (apart from the verbosity of this ritual, which I don't like) is that I'd then have to template `deref` in order to pass the template arguments which `operator()()` uses to `std::unary_function()`. Then, when you use `deref` you'd have to instantiate the template (which is the most annoying side-effect!) as you did in your comment above. All this work, for a couple of typedefs, isn't worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how often you need to do that and how specifically. There is such a thing as a transforming iterator, and you could make one such that

```
vcopy( deref_iter( v.begin() ), deref_iter( v.end() ) );
```

would do what you want. However, that's not that much easier than what you have, and a straightforward function taking a pointer-vector and returning an object-vector would be easier to implement and to use.